# How to calculate read/writes on Firestore query/where operation?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

The Firebase Firestore documentation says:

> **Get multiple documents from a collection**
>
> You can also retrieve
>   multiple documents with one request by querying documents in a
>   collection. For example, you can use where() to query for all of the
>   documents that meet a certain condition, then use get() to retrieve
>   the results:

```
var citiesRef = db.collection('cities');
var query = citiesRef.where('capital', '==', true).get()
    .then(snapshot => {
      snapshot.forEach(doc => {
        console.log(doc.id, '=>', doc.data());
      });
    })
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('Error getting documents', err);
    });
```

If I have a collection with N documents, would I incur a N-read fee or a single read, for the above query?

Is there any way to retrieve the read/write count on a per call basis using the SDK?

As some background for my rational for asking, I have a single collection with a large number of documents (around 20,000). I want to export the entire collection's documents in the most cost efficient manner (least reads).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Every document yielded by a query counts as a document read.  If your query matches and returns N documents, it will cost N document reads.

Comment: So would I pay 20k reads the moment I call myBigCollection.get() or would I pay 1 read each tick of snapshot.forEach(doc =>  { console.log(doc.data()) ?  Would 20k data docs come down in one giant swoop, or would subsequent background calls occur inside the iterator?

Comment: You're billed for all the reads in one chunk, regardless of how the client chooses to consume them.  The documents are all in memory at the same time in the snapshot.

Comment: so the .where() call reads the entire collection or only the documents in the collection that fit the criteria?

Comment: @Mr.Drew You would pay for only those returned. For example, if your collection contained 100k documents but your query filtered the result set to 10k, you would pay for 10k reads. I think behind the scenes the query would operate on the indexes and the paid 'work' would be considered collecting the horizonally distibuted documents from their various locations inside the infrastructure.

Answer (score -1):

The database will read from N documents in order to filter them all. But only the docs who successfully passes the `'capital', '==', true` test will be downloaded locally. You don't have to be scared to have big collections of documents but when you fetch the documents you need to be sure you only get those you need because it is the download of them that slows your app.

Firebase is more efficient when you use low nested data. You want them normalized in many collections instead of subcollections

https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/structure-data

Comment: The question was about firestore and your reference link is for realtime database.