# Do queries count as readings in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

If I have 1000 documents and I run a query to find 3 documents that meet a certain condition, will that count as reading 1000 or 3 documents?

Comment: Can you please post the code you are using. That will help to answer

Comment: I haven't implemented any code yet, I'm trying to get more info and the experiences of other people right now

Comment: But let's say I run a regular query

Comment: I think Doug's answer here explains it best and most succinctly: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50139501/how-to-calculate-read-writes-on-firestore-query-where-operation

Answer (score 38):

Document reads are the fundamental unit of billing in Firestore as they relate to queries.  Individual queries are not a primary unit of billing, but each query will be billed.

You will be billed for all the documents matched by a query, as those documents will be read and sent to the client.  If your query matches no documents, then there is no billing.  If your collection has 1000 documents, but your query returns 3 documents, you are charged 3 reads, not 1000.

The exception is that queries that return no documents are billed for a single document read.  This means every query incurs a cost of at least one document read, no matter the results.  If your query spans multiple requests (because of paging), you are billed at least one document read per request.

Please [consult the documentation for Firestore billing](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/pricing) to get more detailed information.

Comment: This should be marked as the solution. A question: when calling FirestoreRecyclerAdapter adapter.getItemCount(), does this change the document reads counter?

Comment: @user1823280 No

Answer (score 0):

As per your query If you are fetching all documents at once on the client end and running your criteria search it will be counted as a single query.

However, if you use the query method of Firestore it will be also counted as a single query.

**Note:**
*Don't have references yet, I am telling through the personal experience.*

Comment: So I will be charged for only the query, like if the query returns 3 documents, I will be charged for only the 3 documents?

Comment: This answer doesn't adequately explain how billing works for queries.  Please see me answer here (and, even better, the official documentation).